# getOrgChart - Multiple root elements

Tags: orgchart, getorgchart

I am using getOrgChart and would like to know if it is possible to have multiple root elements. For example, I have two managers that have people below them. Instead of listing their common manager, I would like to display the two managers and their staff independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, set the parentId to null

Run the code snippet bellow

```js
       var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{   
            enableEdit: false,
            dataSource: [
          { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Ivan"},
     { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field"},
         { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson"},
         { id: 4, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie"},          
         { id: 5, parentId: 4, Name: "Dragan"},
         { id: 6, parentId: 4, Name: "Petkan"}
    ]
        });
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#people {width: 100%;height: 100%; }
```

```html
<link href="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
<div id="people"></div>
```

Comment: need some help, how are nodes getting connected here ?? we use pid now , right. but I have version 2.5.3 , so don't have knowledge of it .

Comment: @VR7 you can use slinks and clinks, see https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Demos/Slinks